# Enumerate repeated rows

Tags: python

I have a DataFrame in which I have some repeated rows, like this:

```
Person   ID     Country   Value

A        426       USA      1000
A        426       USA      1000
A        426       USA      1000
B        419       CHI      500
B        419       CHI      500
C        510       ALE      2000
C        510       ALE      2000
C        510       ALE      2000
C        510       ALE      2000
```

And I am trying to enumerate each repeated row in order, expecting it to be like this:

```
Person   ID     Country   Value   Times

A        426       USA      1000    1
A        426       USA      1000    2
A        426       USA      1000    3
B        419       CHI      500     1
B        419       CHI      500     2
C        510       ALE      2000    1
C        510       ALE      2000    2
C        510       ALE      2000    3
C        510       ALE      2000    4

I have no idea of how to do it, can you give me some help?
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).  This is covered in quite a few places on line.  I don't have a handy link, or I'd mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use , [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) , The approach is to `groupby` on `ID` and get the cumulative count across the group , additionally `+1` is added to tackle the initial `0` cumcount

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> import pandas
>>> d = StringIO("""
Person,ID,Country,Value
A,426,USA,1000
A,426,USA,1000
A,426,USA,1000
B,419,CHI,500
B,419,CHI,500
C,510,ALE,2000
C,510,ALE,2000
C,510,ALE,2000
C,510,ALE,2000
""")
>>> df['Times'] = df.groupby('ID')['Person'].cumcount()+1
>>> df
  Person   ID Country  Value  Times
0      A  426     USA   1000      1
1      A  426     USA   1000      2
2      A  426     USA   1000      3
3      B  419     CHI    500      1
4      B  419     CHI    500      2
5      C  510     ALE   2000      1
6      C  510     ALE   2000      2
7      C  510     ALE   2000      3
8      C  510     ALE   2000      4
```